# How to make a multi column table in latex?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am making a document in two column format.

I need to introduce the following table in my document:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
        \hline
        S.No. & Rate(2001) & Rate(2010)  \\
        \hline
        01     & 10~~11 & 20 ~~22 \\
        \hline
        02      & 10~~12 & 20 ~~ 25  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It does not work properly.

Comment: simple! (i) read some introduction text about latex (for example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) (ii) find an example of table on site and try to adopt it to your needs, (iii) if you stuck in this, asked here for help. as now, your question is sort of `do-this-for-me, which likely will bot be answered ... welcome to tex.se

Comment: Thanks, @Zarko. I have been struggling with the above mentioned code. Unfortunately, it does not give the exact form I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are. This must work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Your Caption}
\label{yourtable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|cc|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{S.No.} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rate (2001)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rate (2010)} \\
                       & Jan             & Feb            & Jan             & Feb            \\ \hline
01                     & 10              & 11             & 20              & 22             \\ \hline
02                     & 10              & 12             & 20              & 25             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se!  (+1) for first (good) answer :-).

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. How can I introduce a vertical line separating the values of Jan and Feb?

Comment: my suggestion (in my answer) was/is not use vertical lines at all. if you persist to use vertical  lines, than you should ask @hossein331 to  show you how to do this (it is very  simple: `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}`). I also sugest you to read some introductory text about latex, for example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf and see presentation https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ about design of tables.

Comment: @hossein331, thanks for the help. Could you kindly show me how to introduce vertical line separating the values of Jan and Feb?

Comment: you're welcome. I put another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like the following, "more professional looks" of table :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your Caption}
\label{yourtable}
    \begin{tabular}{ l C{9mm}C{9mm} C{9mm}C{9mm} }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{S.No.}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rate (2001)}
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Rate (2010)} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        &   Jan &   Feb     &   Jan &   Feb                     \\
    \midrule
01      &   10  &   11      &   20  &   22                      \\
02      &   10  &   12      &   20  &   25                      \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{your caption}
\label{your-lable}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
                         & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Rate (2001)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rate (2010)} \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{S. No.} & Jan                        & Feb                        & Jan             & Feb            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{01} & 10                         & 11                         & 20              & 22             \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{02} & 10                         & 12                         & 20              & 25             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you only made small changes to the first answer. this should be added to it as edit.